# Rhinoslider with varies height for each page/slide

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I'm using [rhinoslider](http://www.rhinoslider.com/) for my sliding pages. Each pages have different content, and hence different height. AT the moment, I'm having difficulty in setting the height for each page. If I don't set the #slider to have a fix height, then it going to have the height of all the pages, which is way to tall. I know, I could set manually for each page, but is there any way that we can set may be just before sliding to next page, to detect the next item height or something.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="slider">
            <div class="form-step"></div>
            <div class="form-step"></div>
            <div class="form-step"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #545454;
}
```

and this is my js where I want to do something on clickin next-btn:

```
$('#next_btn').live("click",function(){
     // get height of next rhino-item or something
}
```

I've been trying to get the next page height but always return null.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: put your code in jsfiddle

Comment: here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yodann/q8dwtaxu/1/ (note: i put the height as 150px, so people will notice the rhino-slider button at the bottom, but on my actual code, I use auto, which then makes the height as sum of all pages)

Comment: sorry, this is the jsfiddle with 150px http://jsfiddle.net/yodann/q8dwtaxu/6/